# laptop screen bug, need to fix it

Tags: laptop, display, bug

my brother's laptop, an Acer NITRO 5, have this screen issue where the screen casually starts becoming blurry and segmented, but when you produce content (like screenshots and screen recordings) the output is clear, so it's completely a screen bug 
you can watch an example [here](https://streamable.com/tfv208) 
please help! 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is either the display driver in the screen, the GPU output driving the screen, or it could be the cable inside the laptop that goes *to* the screen.

That screenshots come out fine just tell you that the memory the GPU is using and the GPU core is okay. This is a hardware fault somewhere between your GPU and the display itself.

You should take it to your manufacturer or a specialist for repair.